# Why does PHP assume this variable is a string when it hasn't been used anywhere yet?

Tags: php, oop, variable-types

I have two classes:

```
class BaseResource {
  public    $url;
  protected $relativeUrl;
  protected $parentUrl;

  public function BaseResource($relUrl, $parentUrl) {
    $this->relativeUrl = $relUrl;
    $this->parentUrl   = $parentUrl;
    $this->url         = url_to_absolute($parentUrl, $relUrl);
  }
}

class XMLResource extends BaseResource {
  private $xml;

  public function XMLResource($relUrl, $parentUrl, $xml) {
    parent::BaseResource($relUrl, $parentUrl);
    $this->$xml = $xml;
  }
}
```

It's all very simple stuff, but when I execute the following code I get an error.

```
$relUrl = "../something.html";
$parentUrl = "http://example.com/test/index.php";
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xmlRes = new XMLResource($relUrl, $parentUrl, $xml);
```

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string

Why is it being assumed that `XMLResource::xml` is a string?  I haven't used it yet so I would assume it is undefined until it is set and then it takes on the type of whatever it is set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $this->$xml = $xml;
```

should be

```
$this->xml = $xml;
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not that easy to spot, you're in the right line:

```
$this->$xml = $xml;
```

But you must look only at this part:

```
$this->$xml
```

Do this instead:

```
$this->xml = $xml;
```

Background: PHP tries to use the content of `$xml` as the literal variable name, which does not work in your case because it needs a string and you're providing an object (which has no `__toString()` method).

The feature is called [Variable variables<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why PHP is assuming `$xmlRes->xml` is a string but you have an error in your `XMLResource` function:

```
$this->$xml = $xml;
```

should be:

```
$this->xml = $xml;
```

Answer (score 1):

You made 1 tiny mistake, change `$this->$xml = $xml;` to `$this->xml = $xml;`.